# Is there a way to determine what program handles html links depending on which program the link was clicked in?

Tags: url, file-association

Is there a way to determine what program handles html links depending on which program the link was clicked in?

For example, if the link is in an outlook message, I want to it to open in IE since that's what my company codes sites for. Anything else should be open with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default.  What you'd need to have is a program that intercepted all http/https/htm/html/etc. requests, looked at its parent process, then use that information to pass the call off to the actual web browser.

I'm not aware of any such program.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Maybe I'll write such a program....